# Undefined array showing even tho its working

Tags: php

my code
[image]

the error
[image]

I'm getting undefined error but its working.
hope someone point out my mistake

Comment: If you could instead copy and paste your code as text. Once pasted, highlight what you pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve line feeds and white space. This way we don't have to transcribe text from the picture if we want to replicate on our own machines.

Comment: what do you get when you debug $_POST?

Comment: Do you ever access `login.php` without a `POST` request, e.g. as a sign-on page? You didn't check for the existance of those keys before trying to grab them, hence the (potential) error.